# Logging access to a column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, logging, automation, deprecation-warning

I would like to log any access to the column `col` in the table `schema.table`. In particular, I'd like to log the time, user, and command. Is this doable?

The immediate use case is the deprecation of `col` in favor of a new column. Transitioning isn't automatic, and finding all instances is not straightforward, so having some automation support would be helpful. This is related to [What's the best way to deprecate a column in a database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/642000/341362) and [What are the best practices around retiring obsolete database columns?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/363807/56956).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pgAudit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit) to log all access to a column in the PostgreSQL log file.

You would use [object audit logging](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit#object-audit-logging) for that.